# What is the exact objectives of the question ban measure?

Tags: support, post-ban

What are the objective of the post ban feature and how does it accomplish them?

Comment: Please, help me at improving the answer making it faq-like or answer by yourself

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system

Answer (score 3):

### Reasons for its existence

- Improving the quality of users' contributions
- Discourage low quality posts<sup>1</sup>
- Encourage users to make an effort to search for their issue (to avoid duplicates)
- Save moderators a lot of time and energy. The automated post bans may seem harsh at times, but moderator time is a very expensive resource, especially on a site the size of SO. Not having our moderators deal with what's at the very bottom of the trash bin is a very good thing.
- The main reason is to solve the problem of the front page being [flooded with low-quality questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system)

#### Encouraging users to put effort in asking

Achieved through:

- Asking users to review and improve their old questions and answers
- Asking users to contribute in a constructive way (e.g. suggesting edits and providing answers)

<sup>1:</sup> Needs a definition of "low quality"

Comment: I'd add that the automated bans save moderators _a lot_ of time & energy. The automated bans may seem harsh at times, but moderator time is a very expensive resource, especially on a site the size of SO. Not having our moderators deal with what's at the very bottom of the trash bin is a very good thing.

Comment: Automated bans and question quality checks exist for only one reason: to solve the problem of the front page being [flooded with low-quality questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: you have a great experience here. Can you contribute more at explaining us about the history which lead to this choice or about its need? Thanks in advance.