# Is it possible to award the collaboration at reviewing one wikified question / answer with a bounty?

Tags: support, review, bounties

I've opened a wikified post here: [What is the exact objectives of the question ban measure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227294/what-is-the-exact-objectives-of-the-question-ban-measure)

It would be nice to be able to encourage a collaborative review as people are doing ok Wikipedia. I think it could bring to a very nice improvement of the posts.

Is it possible? I could not find anything on the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently bounties only go to the author of the post, not the editors.  This is also the case of CW posts; the bounty only goes to the original author of the post, not any editors or even the user with the most significant percentage of contribution.

Comment: It would be nice to reward contributors..